# How do I update my page content?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to delete a card from my page, I want to remove it as soon as it is swiped and update the contents dynamically without using this code to refresh my entire page:

```
reloadPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
}
```

ion card:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let e of tasks;let i = index" (swipe)="delete(i)">
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-label>{{e.taskName}}</ion-label>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
        <p>{{e.task}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

ts:

```
delete(i) {
   this.tasks.splice(i, 1);
   let newTask = JSON.stringify(this.tasks);
   this.nativeStorage.setItem('tasks', newTask);
   this.reloadPage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splicing the entry from your tasks array should suffice, no need to reload your page:

```
delete(i) {
   this.tasks.splice(i, 1);
}
```

See this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-guohfe?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)